# Windows 7 - Desktop 2.0 and Sticky notes

Tags: windows-7, virtual-desktop, sticky-notes

On Windows 7, I installed [Desktops 2.0 from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881). Now I want to use Sticky Notes on every desktop, however a new sticky note is part of the application which already run on desktop 1 and is not created on another desktop.

I guess I could solve this by forcing multiple instances of Sticky notes. **Can I do that or is there other way to have Sticky notes on multiple desktops?** To use different application for each desktop is not the best solution I guess.

Comment: You are likely going to have to find a third-party Stick Notes application because the Windows 7 version, is entirely different, compared to the Windows 10 version. This would be extremely simply on Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I tried Stickies and SimplyStickyNotes, but it works the same way. I also need to work on my notebook, so I can't use Windows 10.